# What are the difference between a4j:outputpanel and a4j:region?

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

The question says all what is important. When it is necessary to use a a4J:outputpanel and when a4j:region?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says it all:

> The `<a4j:region>` component specifies a part of the JSF component tree to be processed on the server. The region causes all the a4j and rich Ajax controls to execute: decoding, validating, and updating the model. The region causes these components to execute even if not explicitly declared. As such, processing areas can more easily be marked using a declarative approach.

This is like naming all components explicitly in the `execute` attribute to an action. Take this example:

```
<h:inputText id="outerStuff" value="#{bean.blubb}" />
<a4j:region id="innerRegion">
  <h:inputText id="stuff1" value="#{bean.bla}" />
  <h:inputText id="stuff2" value="#{bean.bla2}" />
  <a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.process}" value="click me" />
</a4j:region>
```

all following three `commandButton` definitions are equivalent:

```
  <a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.process}" value="click me" 
      execute="stuff1,stuff2,@this" />
  <a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.process}" value="click me" 
      execute="@region" />
  <a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.process}" value="click me" />
```

The third works because the [showcase documentation](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=region&skin=blueSky) says:

> However, if the controls wrapped with the a4j:region tag and have no execute definitions, they use execute="@region" instead.

In contrast to that, an `<a4j:outputPanel>` is modelled after an `<h:panelGroup>` with the added feature of the `ajaxRendered` attribute. If you leave it off, it behaves like a `panelGroup` (renders a `span` or `div` element). If you enable it, it causes it's contents to be rendered with each AJAX request (unless the component causing the request was annotated `limitRender`).

To summarize: `<a4j:region>` influences how Richfaces executes the view/updates the model and `<a4j:outputPanel>` changes the way the view is rendered.